# Is it possible to run a script based on what other programs do on Mac OS?

Tags: python, macos, shell

Let's say I have simple ToDoApp based on Cloud so it use network when add, delete or done task.  It doesn't provide API and it's not an opensource.

But I would like to run a sync script that logs history whenever I add or perform an action in my app.

Is it possible run script or program based another program activity(or network request).